# How do I successfully connect Django to Azure Cache for Redis?

Tags: django, azure, redis

I have a django application that I have just migrated to MS Azure from Digital Ocean, and the app runs perfectly on Azure.  However, I'm struggling to implement a cache backend with an Azure Cache for Redis service.

I have the following configuration in settings.py:

```
    CACHES = {
        "default": {  
            "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
            "LOCATION": f"redis://<my_redis_service_name>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password={secrets.AZURE_REDIS_PASSWORD},ssl=True,abortConnect=False",
            "OPTIONS": {
                "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
                "COMPRESSOR": "django_redis.compressors.zlib.ZlibCompressor",
            },
        }
    }
```

I have replaced my redis service name with `<my_redis_service_name>`.

With this setup and DEBUG=True, I receive the error:

```
ValueError at /accounts/login/
Redis URL must specify one of the following schemes (redis://, rediss://, unix://)
```

Strange since `redis://` is in the url.  I have verified the keys, and ensured the redis service firewall accepts my VM's IP4 address, as well as making sure port 6380 is open on the VM.  I have also tried various permutations of the connection string, such as:

```
"LOCATION": f'redis://:{secrets.AZURE_REDIS_PASSWORD}@<my_redis_service_name>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,ssl=True,abortConnect=False',
```

No luck. If it's relevant, I'm using Django 4.0.7, Python 3.8, django-cachalot, and jazzband's django-redis package. Azure Cache for Redis states that it's using Redis version 6.0.14.  For what it's worth, my development environment works fine with a local daemonized redis cache at `"LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",`.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: you need to check your connection string and the syntax it follows for azure , it seems syntactically it is incorrect, also check whether the service name you have given `my_redis_service_name ` is the correct host name provided, remote or local

Comment: Thanks, I double checked the service name and it's correct.  Still not connecting.

Answer (score 2):

Since `SSL is mandatory` on AZURE REDIS you need to do something like this:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        "LOCATION": 'rediss://YOUR_REDIS_HOST_NAME:YOUR_REDIS_PORT',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
            'PASSWORD': 'YOUR_REDIS_PASSWORD',
            'SSL': True
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: As mentioned in django_redis Readme we use `rediss://` if we want a SSL connection

Comment: Tried it, but this does not help.  You'll notice `ssl=True` is also in the connection string.

Comment: As I mentioned in the `NOTE` part you had to add `rediss://`

Answer (score 2):

After trying many, many permutations of the connection string and options, I finally hit on a version that worked:

```
"LOCATION": f"rediss://:{secrets.AZURE_REDIS_PASSWORD}@<my_redis_service_name>.redis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/0",
```

Note the `rediss://` schema with the extra 's' for SSL, which is analogous to `HTTPS`, and the  `:` before `{secrets.AZURE_REDIS_PASSWORD}`, which would normally follow a username (there is no username on Azure redis).  Hopefully this helps someone, because as of this writing I have not found documented examples of django redis configs using Azure redis.  Also added `/0` after the port to denote the default redis database.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the above as applied to Django 5.

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache"
        "LOCATION": f"rediss://:{AZURE_REDIS_CACHE_KEY}@redis-qa-ai-app.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/0"
    }
}
```

As mentioned by Milo Persic above, redis has an extra s. If you miss that, calls to Redis will hang and eventually time out.